# Is storing Entity Framework models bad practice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a user object which I load when a user sends a login request - and I'd like to add them to a list of authenticated users. Is using the same POCO object for this list a bad idea? How can I update this object later in a context?

Comment: You can "reattach" the object.  It's a bad idea but I have no good reason to explain why.

Comment: @DanAndrews How alternatively should I track my authenticated user(s) and their associated models, then? I could store IDs but then - it seems like doing a database hit every time I want information about a user is a bad idea. What about when I want to get a players name? Database hit. Am I better off constructing a new model that's populated with the EF model?

Comment: You act like the database hit is painful.  Should be by PK, no?  Otherwise you're monitoring state locally.  Maybe I don't understand the architecture of your application and thus the context of your question.  Speaking generally, I wouldn't abuse the EF Models.

Comment: @DanAndrews It's a game server - so things can be a bit costly. If I want to lookup a users name to send a chat message - I would then need to look the entity up every time they send a message. Seems like a waste?

I guess I'm looking for a flawless way to map EF's POCOs to Buissness Objects or directly use the POCOs as buissness objects.

Comment: I guess I'm used to using my POCOs with EF's entities using AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/) instead of using the heavy EF entity.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'same POCO object'? Are you asking if you should create an entirely new class to store the information in? I would say no, just cache the user.

Comment: Regarding getting a players name, refactor so the client sends the name,id and message along. Cache the info on the client side.

Comment: @CharlieBrown That's exactly what I'm asking. Essentially, can I pop the user off and then cache, manipulate and write it back to the database. Ideally, it looks like a repository pattern suits this.

Comment: @VaughanHilts yes - it was unclear to me what you were doing.  Of course you can keep the user's entity around to send back to the WCF service to reconnect and save to the database.  I would suggest "bootstrapping" the entity to expose only the properties that are needed and add functionality that you may need.  I was under the impression that you wanted to keep a collection of users and maint. them there (not just logged in ones).

Comment: @DanAndrews Yes, I was mainly concerned with having a collections of users on an object (say, a Session) and then someone modifying the User. That is out of scope, though. If you wish to write an answer, you've helped a lot and I'll gladly mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to "bootstrap" the EF object.  That is, create an object which has-a EF object and exposes only the properties that you need as well as extends the object with other methods.  This is what I do with Silverlight applications, my ViewModels take an EF object or DTO and then add OnProp change - the exposed properties of this object modify the EF or DTO object directly which is eventually returned by the WCF service to be reattached and saved.  It essentially becomes another layer of encapsulation.  However the EF / DTO object cannot be modified by the application directly, only through this wrapper object.  The reason is to keep other developers from doing something they shouldn't or something that I didn't expect but still have an object that I'm familiar with on the WCF side to CRUD.